# how to pass percentile inputs to `describe` when using `groupby` and `agg` in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

**How can I combine `describe` with *custom percentiles* and `sum` (or any other function) using agg?**

To get percentiles and other statistics for columns with `groupby`, one can do:

```
df.groupby('A')['revenue'].describe(percentiles=[0.95])
```

If I want `sum` I can do the following, **but I have no idea how to pass the arguments `percentiles` to `agg` method**. :(

```
df.groupby('A',dropna=False)['Revenue'].agg(['sum','describe'])
```

Comment: have you tried `df.groupby('A',dropna=False)['Revenue'].agg(sum).describe(percentiles=[0.95])`? or if you want it in another column you can first do the `groupby` and after that `df_aggegated['describe'] = df_agregated.describe(percentiles=[0.95])`. If you put some test data to test, it would help. Also the `agg` method has an [*args](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html?highlight=*args) parameter where you can pass parameters to your function(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10), 'B':range(10,20)})
pd.concat([df.describe(percentiles=[.2, .4, .6, .8]), df.sum().to_frame('sum').T], axis=0).T
```

Output:

```
   count  mean      std   min   20%   40%   50%   60%   80%   max    sum
A   10.0   4.5  3.02765   0.0   1.8   3.6   4.5   5.4   7.2   9.0   45.0
B   10.0  14.5  3.02765  10.0  11.8  13.6  14.5  15.4  17.2  19.0  145.0
```